# Finding object with specific value

Tags: javascript, object

I have an tree structured object e.g

```
var x = [{
  id: 1,
  children: [{
    id: 11,
    children: [],
  }, {
    id: 12,
    children: [{
      id: 121,
      name:'jogn',
      children: []
    }]
  }]
}, {
  id: 2,
  children: [],
}]
```

And i would like to find object with specific ID in it. I made

```
function printObj(obj , val) {
  for( var i = 0; i < obj.length ; i++){
         if( obj[i].id == val){
         return obj[i];
         }
         if( obj[i].children.length > 0 ){
            printObj( obj[i].children)
         }
    }
}
```

function. The problem is when i invoke it

```
var g = printObj(x , 121);
alert(x.name)
```

it returns undefined instead of jogn altought when i pop some alert if it findes set value it does find it . Why is it returning wrong object then?

Comment: What if you alert `g.name` instead of `x`?

Comment: Also, you don't return anything from the printObj(children) so the recursive result will just disappear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two problems with this line:

```
printObj( obj[i].children);
```

1. It's missing its second argument
2. You need to *return* its result if it finds one

So

```
var possibleResult = printObj( obj[i].children, val);
// -------------------------------------------^^^^^
if (possibleResult) {
    return possibleResult;
}
```

Separately, in your testing, you looked for `x.name` where you wanted `g.name`.

Fixed:

```js
var x = [{
  id: 1,
  children: [{
    id: 11,
    children: [],
  }, {
    id: 12,
    children: [{
      id: 121,
      name: 'jogn',
      children: []
    }]
  }]
}, {
  id: 2,
  children: [],
}];

function printObj(obj, val) {
  for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    if (obj[i].id == val) {
      return obj[i];
    }
    if (obj[i].children.length > 0) {
      var possibleResult = printObj(obj[i].children, val);
      if (possibleResult) {
        return possibleResult;
      }

    }
  }
}

var g = printObj(x, 121);
console.log(g.name);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Ramda](http://ramdajs.com/) is great for object and list work from functional approach - here is your data traversed -

```
    var x = [{
      id: 1,
      children: [{
        id: 11,
        children: [],
      }, {
        id: 12,
        children: [{
          id: 121,
          name: 'jogn',
          children: []
        }]
      }]
    }, {
      id: 2,
      children: [],
    }]


    const findById = (id, list) => map(o => {
      if(o.id === id) return o
      return findById(id, o.children)
    }, list)

    head(flatten(findById(121, x)))
```